# problem in passing parameters in $(document).ready(function() ajax url in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, parameters, routes

My route is

```
Route::get('staff/staffcardview/{dept}',['as' => 'StaffCardView', 'uses' => 'Staff\StaffController@showcards']);
```

and i want to pass parameter to this url from document.ready function using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '{{ URL::route("StaffCardView") }}',
    data: { id: 2 },
```

But it is showing error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: StaffCardView] [URI:
>   staff/staff/staffcardview/{dept}]. (View:
>   D:\VJCET_29_11\vjcetcrm\vjcetcrm\resources\views\staff\staffcardview.blade.php)

Comment: your route has a required parameter defined in the URL, you need to pass that when generating the URL to the route

Answer (score 1):

Your Route has required parameter `{dept}`. Try passing value when creating route or make it as optional parameter

1. `$.ajax({ type: 'get', url: '{{ URL::route("StaffCardView",['dept' => 'somedummyvalue'] ) }}', data: { id: 2 })`
2. 

```
Route::get('staff/staffcardview/{dept?}',['as' => 'StaffCardView', 'uses' => 'Staff\StaffController@showcards']);

...

$.ajax({ type: 'get', url: '{{ URL::route("StaffCardView") }}', data: { id: 2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'get', url: "{{ route('StaffCardView', ['dept' => 2]) }}", data: { id: 2 },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the parameter in your route, do like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'get', 
    url: "{{ route('StaffCardView', $card->debt) }}", 
    data: { id: 2 },
```